# Debugger break command in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

In Visual Studio (C#) there is a command

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

that lets you automatically hop into the debugger even without setting a breakpoint.  Is there such a thing for VS Code?  I'd especially like it for rust.  I tried just writing "let x = 1/0" but that just crashes the program.

I'm using the cppvsdbg debugger for windows.

Comment: Try [DebugBreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak) or [__debugbreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I'm gonna try to find a way to make that work in rust.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through what David Cullen suggested in the comments leads to a few options:

- [std::intrinsics::breakpoint](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.breakpoint.html) This needs nightly rust.
- [The breakpoint crate](https://fitzgen.github.io/breakpoint-rs/breakpoint/index.html) This doesn't even compile but it would have been nice.
- [The WinApi](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.6/i686-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/debugapi/fn.DebugBreak.html) this is rather OS specific but it works for my case.  The OS dependency can at least probably be mitigated [using conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html).  To use the library, add:

  ```
  [dependencies.winapi]
  version = "0.3.7"
  features = ["debugapi"]
  ```

to Cargo.toml and call it using

```
unsafe {
    winapi::um::debugapi::DebugBreak();
}
```

However it turns out that even this approach doesn't work across crates, it just crashes.